# Compare two string in js and find difference

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

how to compare two strings purely, and provide specific result such as highlight extra word, wrong word & skip word in 2nd string. for eg.

```
var x = "This is the first original string in javascript language." </br>
var y = "This is not the first org string in language."

diff =  wrong word ="org"<br>
        Extra word ="not"<br>
        skip word ="javascript"
```

//here is slice of my code but in some case my program fails

```
  var x = "here is some value of string";
  var y = "here is the some val string";
  var k=0; 
  var SkipWrd="";
 for(var i=0; i<y.length;i++){ 
    var sktmp="";
    var swtmp=0;
     for(var j=0; j<=2;j++) { 
         if(x[k]!="undefined"){ 
             if(y[i]==x[k+j]){  

                 SkipWrd+=sktmp;
                 skip+=swtmp;
                 H_wrd +=  typ_wrd[i]+" ";
                 org_para+= sktmp+x[k+j]+" ";

                 k+=j+1;
                 break;
             }
            else{
             sktmp+= "<mark>"+ x[k+j]+" "+ "</mark>";
             swtmp++; 
             if(j==2 && y[i]!=x[k+j]){
                 err++;
                 Err_Wrd+=y[i]+" ";
                 H_wrd += "<span id='H-Err'>" + typ_wrd[i] + "</span> ";
                 org_para+="<span id='O-Err'>" +x[k]+" "+ "</span> ";

                 k++;
             }
            }
        } 
     }
 }
```

Comment: You can use the ```split(' ')``` function on each string to convert them to arrays. Then iterate through each element and compare them accordingly to find the results you require.
If you are expecting some one to write the code for you, then you are in the wrong place.

Comment: @Vivek i want help to make more strong my code. plz check again

Comment: Good that you posted your attempt now.

Comment: thanks ,it solve my problem a little bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used a word by word comparison approach rather than the character by character approach you used. The overall logic is similar.
The below code will work for your example, but there are many more cases that might go wrong.

```js
var x = "This is the first original string in javascript language.";
var y = "This is not the first org string in language.";

x=x.split(' ');
y=y.split(' ');

var i=0,j=0;
while (1) {
  if (!x[i] || !y[j]) break;
  
  if (x[i] == y[j]) {
    i++;
    j++;
    continue;
  }
  
  if (x[i] == y[j+1]) {
    console.log('Extra word : ', y[j]);
    i++;
    j+=2;
    continue;
  }
  
  if (x[i+1] == y[j]) {
    console.log('Skip word: ', x[i]);
    i+=2;
    j++;
    continue;
  }
  
  if (x[i+1] == y[j+1]) {
    console.log('Wrong word: ', y[j]);
    i++;
    j++;
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer but you can make it a bit more concise by removing the `continue` statements and make each `if` after the first one into an `if else` so that only one is run during each iteration.